# Client error: `POST { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "One of content, or gcs_content_uri must be set.", "status": "INVALID (truncated

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

I try to call post api from laravel with GuzzleHttp\Client.but we try tp pass api key with different ways but not get output if i append API key in url then i get this result.

```
//intiate client
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
                'base_uri' => 'https://language.googleapis.com/',
            ]);

//api call for get data entitiwise

$response = $client->request('POST','/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=' . $apiKey, $finalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your api key. You have to set either 'content' or 'gcsContentUri' in your request: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document